# I can't find my apps

Tags: backup, restore

I recently backed up ubuntu and removed its partition. Then  created a new partition which is larger. I restored the backup and only got my documents.I used the default backup application, I just searched in unity. I don't have my apps, like Chrome, Skype, Screen capture etc. How should I fix this?

Comment: How did you backup and restore? Kindly edit your question and include this info.

Comment: How did you create the backup?

Answer (score 0):

This application does not back up your installed programs. You will have to reinstall them.

Comment: okay wow. but in case of another time, which application can help me backup my apps

Comment: how did you make the backup?

Comment: Mr T Aptik can help you with that http://www.tecmint.com/aptik-a-tool-to-backuprestore-your-favourite-ppas-and-apps-in-ubuntu/

Comment: @Mr.T Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)

Comment: Sad, but true...